# Laravel Breeze Next and Sanctum Token Mismatch

Tags: laravel

First of all this is working fine when I do it in localhost but if I try it to deploy in my production server the issue token mismatch appear when I try to login.
I already configure the FRONTEND_URL

Comment: did you update values of SESSION_DOMAIN and SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS in your .env file? Also check your request header actually contains the token when your client makes a req to the server.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.